# Avro: deserialize json - schema with optional fields

Tags: json, avro

There are a lot of questions and answers on stackoverflow on the subject, but no one that helps.

I have a schema with optional value:

```
{
 "type" : "record",
 "name" : "UserSessionEvent",
 "namespace" : "events",
 "fields" : [ {
   "name" : "username",
   "type" : "string"
 }, {
   "name" : "errorData",
   "type" : [ "null", "string" ],
   "default" : null
 }]
}
```

And I'm trying deserialize json w/o this field:

```
{
 "username" : "2271AE67-34DE-4B43-8839-07216C5D10E1",
 "errorData" : { "string":"070226AC-9B91-47CE-85FE-15AA17972298"}
}
```

using code:

```
val reader = new GenericDatumReader[GenericRecord](schema)
val decoder = DecoderFactory.get().jsonDecoder(schema, json)
reader.read(null, decoder)
```

and I got: `org.apache.avro.AvroTypeException: Expected field name not found: errorData`

The only way that works is json

```
{
 "username" : "2271AE67-34DE-4B43-8839-07216C5D10E1",
 "errorData" : null
```

}

Is there a way to deserialize json w/o this field?

Another question: when this field is here, I should write

```
{
 "username" : "2271AE67-34DE-4B43-8839-07216C5D10E1",
 "errorData" : { "string":"070226AC-9B91-47CE-85FE-15AA17972298"}
```

}

Is there a way to deserialize a "normal" json:

```
{
 "username" : "2271AE67-34DE-4B43-8839-07216C5D10E1",
 "errorData" : "070226AC-9B91-47CE-85FE-15AA17972298"
}
```

?

Comment: are you using scala?

Comment: Did you ever solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

case 1 is working fine in java .

```
{
"username" : "2271AE67-34DE-4B43-8839-07216C5D10E1",
"errorData" : { "string":"070226AC-9B91-47CE-85FE-15AA17972298"}
}
```

for case 2 Your schema is defined for union. You can update you schema as below to deserialize  json.

```
 {
   "username" : "2271AE67-34DE-4B43-8839-07216C5D10E1",
   "errorData" : "070226AC-9B91-47CE-85FE-15AA17972298"
 }

{
  "type" : "record",
  "name" : "UserSessionEvent",
  "namespace" : "events",
  "fields" : [ {
                "name" : "username",
                "type" : "string"
             }, {
                "name" : "errorData",
                "type" :  "string" ,
                "default" : null
               }]
}
```

Comment: For the above mentioned 2 schemas, is it possible to eliminate `errorData` from the message? Meaning, can `{"username" : "2271AE67-34DE-4B43-8839-07216C5D10E1"}` ever be a valid message?

Comment: Looks like prior to this commit https://github.com/apache/avro/commit/7e4037de2a891fa738aaf8a4fc56f424d6c6833a#diff-c7934590c625ba67bf1b2ad5511a4f58R97 (https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AVRO-388) Avro GenericDatumReader was able to use default values for skipped fields, but no longer can do it.

Comment: IIUC the second part of accepted answer is incorrect. If value is not provided, default will be used. But null is of type null not string, so this will not work. To fix that  you can use type ["string","null"]. So this will allow you to omit `errorData`, but will block you from passing 'normal' json. So IIUC, the AVRO design is flawed as it disallows to use normal json format.

Comment: With this solution, I get an error when I use the maven plugin:  Execution default of goal org.apache.avro:avro-maven-plugin:1.10.0:schema failed: Invalid default for field blabla: null not a "string"